# NSNumberFormatter display 1,000,000 as 1mln etc

Tags: iphone, ios, formatting, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

Like described in title, is there any way to format huge number like 1,000,000 (1 mln) or 45,500,000 (45,5 mln) to string to display shortened version of this number name. I just want to prevent all advices to do it manually. I know how to do this that way. I just want to find out if there is any easier way using NSNumberFormatter.

Cheers,

Lukasz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest a combination of manual and using NSNumberFormatter. My idea is to subclass NSNumberFormatter. If the number you are formatting is > 1,000,000, you can divide it, use the super implementation to format the result, and append " mln" to the end. Only do the part which you can't have done for you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a rough sketch of a NSNumberFormatter subclass that does it (sorry, the formatting is slightly off):

```
@implementation LTNumberFormatter

@synthesize abbreviationForThousands;
@synthesize abbreviationForMillions;
@synthesize abbreviationForBillions;

-(NSString*)stringFromNumber:(NSNumber*)number
{
if ( ! ( abbreviationForThousands || abbreviationForMillions || abbreviationForBillions ) )
{
    return [super stringFromNumber:number];
}

double d = [number doubleValue];
if ( abbreviationForBillions && d > 1000000000 )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [super stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d / 1000000000]], abbreviationForBillions];
}
if ( abbreviationForMillions && d > 1000000 )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [super stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d / 1000000]], abbreviationForMillions];
}
if ( abbreviationForThousands && d > 1000 )
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [super stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d / 1000]], abbreviationForThousands];
}
    return [super stringFromNumber:number];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think that there is a way to do this with NSNumberFormatter. You're on your own on this.